# Index Match multiple criteria with one OR condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following `index` `match`formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B;(MATCH(1;($C:$C="Value1")*($D:$D=$F3)*($E:$E=OR("X";"Y";"Z"));0)));"")
```

however, I want `$E:$E=OR("X";"Y";"Z")` to be one of the conditions of the `match`: I want to see if **E** has one of these three values. 
Currently it gives an error. How to achieve this condition in the match statement?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend restricting the ranges, using whole columns will make the formula slow......but try using `ISNUMBER/MATCH` for your OR, I.e.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B;MATCH(1;($C:$C="Value1")*($D:$D=$F3)*ISNUMBER(MATCH($E:$E;{"X";"Y";"Z"};0));0));"")`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

or you can try the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B;(MATCH(1;($C:$C="Value1")*($D:$D=$F3)*(($E:$E="X")+($E:$E="Y")+($E:$E="Z"));0)));"")
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.

Answer (score 0):

In general, more than one condition being checked in OR logic can be true. So simply using a sum like ($E:$E="X")+($F:$F="Y")+($G:$G="Z") can give incorrect results (>1). Instead, check if the sum is >0, like this (0<($E:$E="X")+($F:$F="Y")+($G:$G="Z")). This expression gives Boolean TRUE/FALSE results, but they become 1/0 when involved in arithmetic calculations -- if there is no further calculation yet, just multiply the expression by 1.

In summary: AND logic multiples several logic expressions. OR logic checks if the sum of several logic expressions >0. The only other logic function you need is NOT, which is 1 - logic expression. Now you have all the building blocks you need to construct any complex logic expression.

Also, if you put the entire logic expression inside INDEX(expression, 0,1), you don't need to use Control+Shift+Enter. More recent versions of Excel deal with the array without needing INDEX or C+S+E.